# How can I specify the movement direction for text objects?

Tags: cursor-motions

How can I specify a direction (for going backwards) for commands working on text objects like `2caw`? E.g. I like to make `2caw` replace `bbb ccc` in `aaa bbb ccc ddd` while on `c`.

Comment: You don't ... You go back one word, and change forward from there: `ge2caw` (also `b` or `2b` instead of `ge`, depending on which `c` the cursor initially is - `ge` is safer).

Comment: Ok, so text object selection only works forwards. Thanks!

Comment: There are plugins (e.g. https://github.com/wellle/targets.vim) that work on objects "behind" or "after" the cursor ( *last* or *next* text-object), but I don't know about one that does what you are asking.